# How to add a line break to an Chrome.i18n message string

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Title says it all. In the [message of Chrome.i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/i18n) how can I add a line break so that world appears on a new line?

```
  {
    "search_string": {
      "message": "hello world",
      "description": "The string we search for. Put %20 between words that go together."
    },
    ...
  }
```

Things I have tried

```
"message": "hello\\nworld"
"message": "hello<br>world"
"message": "hello\u000dworld"
```

Comment: In JSON string you can use `\n`. The problem is likely the CSS of the element: it must have something like `white-space: pre-line`.

Comment: Though I have not tried this but as per this [link](https://phrase.com/docs/guides/formats/chrome-json/) 
`"key_with_line-break": {
        "message": "This translations contains\na line-break."
      }`
Above should work.